# Not able to configure connection string in ASP.net MVC Core 5.0 & Entity Framework Core application

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm getting below error when I configure SQL Connection in ASP.Net Core MVC 5 and Entity Framework core.

I've configured in Startup.cs file:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddDbContext<VMSDBContext>(
               options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("VMSDatabase"))
            );
        }
```

My appsettings.json file:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "VMSDatabase": "Server=.;Database=VMS;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

> InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

Comment: You're looking for a connection called "VMSDatabase" in your code. But you've configured a connection called "AgileOneVMSDatabase" in your appsettings. Change either one of them so to the same and this should solve your issue.

Comment: It's a typo error. Still the error exists.

Comment: Can you share the code for your VMSDBContext claas?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a connection called "VMSDatabase" in your code. But you've configured a connection called "AgileOneVMSDatabase" in your appsettings. Change either one of them so to the same and this should solve your issue.

Comment: It's a typo error. Still the error exists.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I guess the reason why you faced this issue is you used the wrong VMSDBContext's constructor method. If this class's
constructor method doesn't contains the DbContextOptions parameter, it will face this error.

I suggest you could change it like below:

```
public VMSDBContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) {}
```

Comment: I already have a constructor                                                                                                 public VMSDBContext(DbContextOptions<VMSDBContext> options)  : base(options) {}

Comment: Could you please share your dbcontext codes and startup's codes?

Comment: public partial class VMSDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public VMSDBContext()
        {

        }

        public VMSDBContext(DbContextOptions<VMSDBContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
            
        }

        public virtual DbSet<AssignmentDetail> AssignmentDetails { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AssignmentExtensionProcess> 
             AssignmentExtensionProcesses { get; set; }                                                                     
   }

Comment: public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddDbContext<VMSDBContext>(
  options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AgileOneVMSDatabase"))
            ); } }

Comment: Why your VMSDBContext  has two contract method?  `public VMSDBContext() { } public VMSDBContext(DbContextOptions<VMSDBContext> options) : base(options) { } `? Please remove the previous one, like this `public VMSDBContext(DbContextOptions<VMSDBContext> options) : base(options) { } `

Comment: I have removed the first constructor. still I'm getting the same error.

Comment: It seems you are using partial class, could you please post all the class which is related with this VMSDBContext.